# Как нарисовать прямоугольник из прерывистой линии?

Tags: python, pillow, pil

Как нарисовать прямоугольник из прерывистой линии c помощью Pillow?

Comment: А сами вы что-то пробовали сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, ответ взят [отсюда](https://progi.pro/punktirnaya-ili-punktirnaya-liniya-s-python-pillow-4552125).

> Я решил написать идею, которую я предложил в комментариях, а именно
> рисовать фигуры сплошными линиями, а затем накладывать пороговое
> шумное изображение, чтобы стирать части линии.
>
> Я сделал весь шум на меньшем изображении, а затем расширил его, чтобы
> шум был "более сложен" вместо крошечных капель.
>
> Так что это всего лишь генерация тестового изображения:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/python3

 
 import numpy as np from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
 
 
 
 # Make empty black image im = Image.new('L', (640,480))
 
 
 
 # Draw white rectangle and ellipse draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) draw.rectangle([20,20,620,460],outline=255)
 draw.ellipse([100,100,540,380],outline=255)
```

> И это создает наложение шума и накладывает его - вы можете просто
> удалить это предложение и объединить два комка кода:

```
# Make noisy overlay, 1/4 the size, threshold at 50%, scale up to full-size noise = np.random.randint(0,256,(120,160),dtype=np.uint8)
noise = (noise>128)*255 noiseim = Image.fromarray(noise.astype(np.uint8)) noiseim = noiseim.resize((640,480), resample=Image.NEAREST)
# Paste the noise in, but only allowing the white shape outlines to be affected im.paste(noiseim,mask=im) im.save('result.png')
```

> В результате получается следующее:
>
> [image]
>
> Сплошное изображение выглядит так:
>
> [image]
>
> Шум такой:
>
> [image]